# Ecliplse, toolbar icons not rendered at start

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem when starting eclipse IDE. Icons not fully drawn.

[image]

I need to hover them with my mouse to show them up. Bat i dont want to do this every time i start eclipse ide.

[image]

I am using linux(arch) and kde.